# Cannot add to list of items in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, list, uitableview, onclick

Its been a while since I used ReactJS and I need to create a list of items that I can add to and remove. I've added an onClick event to my li to remove it. I also have a button to add new items, these seem to work but the state is not updating.

```
var new_items = [...Array(1)].map((val, i) => `No Items`);
<ul className="App-list">
   {new_items.map((item, i) => (<li key={`item_${i}`} onItemClick={onItemClick(i)}>{ item }</li>))}
</ul>
```

the onClick function is here

```
function onItemClick(num) {
  this.setState({
     new_items: this.state.new_items.concat('new value')
  })
}
```

I just need to either delete a line from the List or Add depending on status but even though it runs it does not update the state. Can someone give me either a batter way of updating a list of rows dynamically or tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share the constructor of the class where onItemClick is defined?

Comment: That may be where I'm going wrong as there is no Constructor, I simply call the function from the li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a constructor as follows:

```
class MyClassName {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            new_items: [] // or null or any other initial value depending on your use case
        }
        this.onItemClick = this.onItemClick.bind(this);
    }
    function onItemClick(num){ ... }
}
```

Then while calling the onClick function you call it as follows:

```
onItemClick={this.onItemClick(i)}
```

Also, if you are using the generic `onClick` functionality, you would have to change `onItemClick` to `onClick`:

```
<li key={`item_${i}`} onClick={()=>this.onItemClick(i)}>
```

Since you are not using the event information from the click, you have to add an anonymous function that calls your desired `onClick` handler. Hence the `()=>this.onItemClick(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Class Component you have to call the method with the context of class

```
onItemClick={this.onItemClick(i)}
```

Comment: And also bind this onItemClick method in constructor of class

Comment: If I use your code I get a warning telling me my event isn't used so what more do I need to do to prevent that?

Comment: You are  receiving this warning because you didn't bind this function with class, for that you can 

`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onItemClick= this.onItemClick.bind(this);
  }`

Comment: A better option to define your function as **arrow function** to get rid of these binding issues.